How do I override the delete() method in Django's DeleteView to send a success message?
I'm using Django 5.0.3. I have a job listings app, with a DeleteListingView. I want to override the delete() method, so that I can use messages.success() to send a message to the success url's template once a listing is deleted.
However, the delete() method isn't being overridden. A listing gets deleted, and I'm redirected to the correct url, but the message isn't sent. I've even tried to add a print() statement inside delete() to see if it appears in cmd, but it doesn't.
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.contrib import messages

from django.urls import reverse_lazy

from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView, DeleteView, CreateView

from .models import Listings

class ListingsListView(ListView):
    model = Listings
    template_name = 'listings/listings_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'listings'


class DeleteListingView(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Listings
    template_name = 'listings/listing_delete.html'
    context_object_name = 'listing'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('listings')

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        listing = self.get_object()
        listing_title = listing.job_title  

        messages.success(self.request, f"Listing titled '{listing_title}' was deleted successfully.")
        print(f"delete() has been overridden successfully.") # To appear in cmd
        return super().delete(request, *args, **kwargs)

and in listings_list.html template:
{% for message in messages %}
   <p> {{ message }}</p>
{% endfor %}

Nothing I've tried is working, and I can't seem to find a solution anywhere. What am I missing?
#Update:
After research, even using ChatGPT, I still can't make the custom delete() method execute. I've tried a function-based view, and it worked. The messages.success() was executed accordingly, and displayed in the success_url's template. Here's the view:
def delete_item(request, pk):
    listing = get_object_or_404(Listings, pk=pk)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        listing_title = listing.job_title
        listing.delete()
        messages.success(request, f"Listing titled '{listing_title}' was deleted successfully.")
        return redirect(reverse('listings'))

    return render(request, 'listings/listing_delete.html', {'listing': listing})


Since Django 4.0 DeleteView uses the FormMixin and hence depends on the form_valid method instead. As a consequence it now also supports the SuccessMessageMixin which you should use:
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin


class DeleteListingView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Listings
    template_name = 'listings/listing_delete.html'
    context_object_name = 'listing'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('listings')
    success_message = "Listing titled '%(title)s' was deleted successfully."
    
    def get_success_message(self, cleaned_data):
        return self.success_message % dict(
            cleaned_data,
            title=self.object.job_title,
        )


Settings.py:
Make sure you have 'django.contrib.messages' in your INSTALLED_APPS, and 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware' in your MIDDLEWARE setting.
Template:
Ensure you have {% if messages %} around your messages loop in your template. This is to prevent rendering the loop if there are no messages.
Here's your updated template:
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        <p>{{ message }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

views.py
messages.success(request,"was deleted successfully.")


Thank you @Bavaliya Nikunj. I already checked, and everything in settings.py checks out. The problem, however, is that the modified delete() method is not being called when the view is executed. Therefore, since messages.success() is inside delete(), it isn't executed either.

added view file code check it

I appreciate your help, although the problem is that the custom delete() method is being ignored by DeleteListingView. Both messages.success(), and the template code work fine when I use a function-based view, as indicated in my update.
